# Collating code files in multiple locations

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, code-coverage, coverage.py

I'm trying to use `coverage.py` on my `unittest`-based tests.
I see that there are multiple kinds of paths and they're not collated, so the coverage data is wrong.

```
/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/<package>/file.py
/<package>/file.py
something.py
```

How can I tell `coverage.py` to treat the paths the same (e.g. to remove the "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages" prefix)?

Answer (score 0):

Create a [[paths] section](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/v4.5.x/config.html#paths) in your configuration file.

Maybe you could help me out: this is easily the most over-looked thing in the coverage.py configuration file.  What can I do in the docs to make it more easily found?